# How to call certain functions depending on what generic type is passed in

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

In the following code, I'm trying to make a short-hand function to get values of different types. It's obviously throwing a compile error. Does anyone know how I can achieve that?

```
private T Get<T>(string key)
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            {
                return this.httpContext.Session.GetInt32(key).Value;
            }

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            {
                return this.httpContext.Session.GetString(key);
            }

            return this.httpContext.Session.GetInt32(key);
        }
```

Comment: I think you're going to find it will be simpler just to have a separate function for each type than to try and wedge it through a generic function.

Comment: You may be better off with a set of `GetInt`, `GetString`, etc functions. They're easier to type than `Get<int>`, and they restrict the set of types that can be gotten (what happens when someone calls `Get<BaseController>` - your only real choice is to throw an exception). By having a fixed set of functions, you restrict the bullets accessible to those intent on shooting themselves in the foot

Comment: Hmmm... I see. I'll do that if someone doesn't come up with a way to do it with generics.

Comment: Ok... I'm convinced. I'll do separate functions.

Comment: You can just cast the result. To support value types, you have to cast to `object` first, otherwise the compiler won't trust you that the cast could succeed generally. See marked duplicate. I do however agree with the other comments. Almost always, if in a generic method you find yourself actually examining the type parameter itself and executing different code based on that comparison, the method shouldn't be generic.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a type without casting, you need to cast it before returning it:

```
var data = this.httpContext.Session.GetInt32(key).Value;
if (data == null || data == DBNull.Value){
   return default(T);
}
else{
   return (T)data;
}
```

Comment: This would work for class types... unfortunately it doesn't work for value types like int32, etc...

Comment: @KeyvanSadralodabai in theory it should be the answer to the problem. I updated the answer to solve your possible scenario.

Comment: Cannot cast expression of type int to type T. That's the error message I get.